# Moving Videos folder into HDD and having a link of it in SSD

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive, ssd

So I Currently have my `/home` on an SSD but I also have an HDD mounted to `/mnt/hdd1`

Now, I want to keep the big files like movies on my HDD. How do I move the Movies folder into my HDD while keeping the nice link in nautilus "Places" menu?

I tried to just move the movies folder on HDD and then making a Link of it but that seemed to just make a copy of the Videos folder that I have on SSD.

[image]

Comment: How is the "nice" link the PLaces menu set up now? IIRC Nautilus adds a places entry for the Videos folder in the home directory, and you can add bookmarks. Which option are you using?

Comment: In the picture you see Videos under Places with an icon before it. Like that I ment.

Comment: You can change the location of the Videos folder: see http://askubuntu.com/a/483866/158442

Comment: Okay, I will try to use the method in the link and see how it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy the contents of your Videos folder to a folder called `Videos` on your HDD, let's say `/mnt/hdd1/Videos`.
2. Open a terminal and type `mv ~/Videos ~/Videos.old`.
3. Type `ln -s /mnt/hdd1/Videos/ ~/`. This will create a link from that Videos folder in your HDD into your home directory (which is on the SSD).
4. If you're on Ubuntu 14.04, I believe "Nautilus" will automatically fix the Videos icon and Places, but if it doesn't, do:

   ```
   sed -i~ '/^XDG_VIDEOS/s|.*|XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"|' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
   ```

   That command should fix it.

Close all Nautilus windows and open again. Verify that the Videos icon still looks the same and you can click it under Places. Verify the symlink by doing `ls -l ~`.

Once done, you can safely remove the `Videos.old` folder in your Home directory.

Comment: What do you think is the better method now? Yours or the one that was posted as a link under my question.

Comment: Hmm, I never before tried @muru's suggestion of changing the path in `user-dirs.dirs`. I just tried it right now though, but it doesn't give the desired outcome. When I click on `Videos` under Places, it takes me to my HDD folder, but the actual "Videos" directory under my home directory is just a normal, empty folder. I suggest my method is better because it makes both the link under Places as well as the actual directory in your Home folder take you to the same place.

Comment: Allright, I will give yours a try.

Comment: Okay, your solution works, and also the other solution works. It just needed a log out with the current user for me to start working. I will now think which one is better.